# How to use libpostal in my java code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
AddressExpander expander = AddressExpander.getInstance();
ExpanderOptions options = new ExpanderOptions.Builder().build();
```

Comment: why did you need to tag C?

Comment: you need to elaborate a little for us to be of any help.

Comment: hey suraj libpostal is a C library

Comment: Hi Clock, libpostal is a library written in C which is used for address normalization. I want to use that library in my spring boot application. There are no maven dependancy available for libpostal

Comment: If you want to use a C library in Java, you would have to write a JNI binding for that. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Or use google and find the JNI binding, which the developers of libpostal conveniently already created: https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal

Comment: Hey @dunni I want to integrate it in my spring boot application, trying to figure out how to ?

Comment: Have you read my link? Any specific problems while you followed the documentation to build and include it in your project?

Comment: Not getting on how to start..i am working on windows, not on ubuntu..could you tell the steps for setting up this library

Answer (score 1):

Have a read on the section "Installation (Windows)" of the C library documentation in order to install it under windows (https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal#installation-windows); once installed use the JNDI binding in order to make the calls between your java application and libpostal(https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal).

@dunni already answered this for you.

Comment: Thanks, and i also had a doubt that whether libpostal supports the locations worldwide or only for USA

Comment: @StephenCells as mentioned in their official documentation: "The goal of this project is to understand location-based strings in every language, everywhere.", so it understand locations worldwide.